# How to add sort by filters to the custom collections magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, sorting

I would like to display **Sort By** filter options to the order collection Magento2 at the front-end and display the results.

Sort by options are '**processing**','**cancelled**', '**hold**' etc.

Can anyone advise how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Order\History" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Order**

**History.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Order;

use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactoryInterface;

class History extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'VendoreName_ModuleName::order/history.phtml';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config
     */
    protected $_orderConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    protected $orders;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactoryInterface
     */
    private $orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status
     */
    protected $orderStatus;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;

    protected $_urlInterface;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status $orderStatus
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status $orderStatus,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $orderCollectionFactory, $customerSession, $orderConfig, $data);
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
        $this->orderStatus = $orderStatus;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    }

    public function getAllOrderStatus()
    {
        return $this->orderStatus->toOptionArray();
    }

    public function getCurrentURL()
    {
        return $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
    }

    public function getOrderStatusURL($statusVal)
    {
        $link = $this->getHistoryPageURL();
        $paramsData = $this->request->getParams();
        if (count($paramsData)) {
            $link .= "?";
            /* Page Number */
            if (isset($paramsData['p'])) {
                $link .= "p=" . $paramsData['p'] . "&";
            }
            /* Page Limit Number */
            if (isset($paramsData['limit'])) {
                $link .= "limit=" . $paramsData['limit'] . "&";
            }
            $link .= "status=" . $statusVal . "&";
        } else {
            $link .= "?";
            $link .= "status=" . $statusVal . "&";
        }
        $link = rtrim(rtrim($link, "&"), "?");
        return $link;
    }

    public function getHistoryPageURL()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl("sales/order/history");
    }

    /**
     * Get customer orders
     *
     * @return bool|\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    public function getOrders()
    {

        /* Get order status */
        $orderStatus = $this->request->getParam('status');
        if (!$orderStatus) {
            $orderStatus = $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses();
        } else {
            $orderStatus = [];
            $orderStatus[] = $this->request->getParam('status');
        }

        /* Get Customer id */
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }

        /* Get order data */
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $orderStatus]
            )->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'desc'
            );
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }

    /**
     * Provide order collection factory
     *
     * @return CollectionFactoryInterface
     * @deprecated 100.1.1
     */
    private function getOrderCollectionFactory()
    {
        if ($this->orderCollectionFactory === null) {
            $this->orderCollectionFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CollectionFactoryInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get message for no orders.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     * @since 102.1.0
     */
    public function getEmptyOrdersMessage()
    {
        return __('You have placed no orders or no any selected order status found.');
    }

}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/order**

**history.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History $block */
$orderStatus = $block->getAllOrderStatus();
?>
<?php $_orders = $block->getOrders(); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('info') ?>
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)) : ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
        <div class="field  required" style="display: flex;float: right;flex-direction: row;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
            <label class="label" for="Sort By" style="display: block;margin: 0 10px;" >
                <span>Order Status</span>
            </label>
            <div>
                <select name="status" title="Order Status" onchange="location = this.value;" >
                    <option value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getHistoryPageURL()) ?>">All</option>
                    <?php foreach ($orderStatus as $orderStatusVal) : ?>
                            <?php if($orderStatusVal['value']) : ?>
                                <?php
                                $selectedVal = '';
                                if ($block->getCurrentURL() == $block->getOrderStatusURL($orderStatusVal['value'])) {
                                    $selectedVal = "selected='selected'";
                                }
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getOrderStatusURL($orderStatusVal['value'])) ?>"
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $selectedVal ?>
                                    >
                                    <span>
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($orderStatusVal['label'])) ?>
                                    </span>
                                </option>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Orders')) ?></caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?></th>
                    <?= $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header') ?>
                    <th scope="col" class="col total"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col actions"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Action')) ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_order->getRealOrderId()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                        <?php $extra = $block->getChildBlock('extra.container'); ?>
                        <?php if ($extra) : ?>
                            <?php $extra->setOrder($_order); ?>
                            <?= $extra->getChildHtml() ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_order->getStatusLabel()) ?></td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewUrl($_order)) ?>" class="action view">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('View Order')) ?></span>
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder::class)->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
                                <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */
                                $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
                                    ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
                                ?>' class="action order">
                                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reorder')) ?></span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()) : ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getEmptyOrdersMessage()) ?></span></div>
    <div class="show-order-sort-by" style="display: flex;flex-direction: row-reverse;flex-wrap: nowrap;justify-content: flex-start;align-items: center;">
        <div class="field  required" style="display: flex;float: right;flex-direction: row;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
            <label class="label" for="Sort By" style="display: block;margin: 0 10px;" >
                <span>Order Status</span>
            </label>
            <div>
                <select name="status" title="Order Status" onchange="location = this.value;" >
                    <option value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getHistoryPageURL()) ?>">All</option>
                    <?php foreach ($orderStatus as $orderStatusVal) : ?>
                            <?php if($orderStatusVal['value']) : ?>
                                <?php
                                $selectedVal = '';
                                if ($block->getCurrentURL() == $block->getOrderStatusURL($orderStatusVal['value'])) {
                                    $selectedVal = "selected='selected'";
                                }
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getOrderStatusURL($orderStatusVal['value'])) ?>"
                                    <?= /* @noEscape */ $selectedVal ?>
                                    >
                                    <span>
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($orderStatusVal['label'])) ?>
                                    </span>
                                </option>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

> **Output**

[image]